# how to stream jpeg frame from java client to python server

Tags: java, c++, python, sockets, jpeg

i am developing an android application wherein i have to send a frame in jpeg format allocated to a BufferedArrayOutputStream (baos variable in code). I convert this baos into a byte array to write into the socket.
On the server side i would like to reconstruct the image in jpeg format. If i write the data received in a variable to a '.jpg' file on the server, on opening the file, it gives an error like "file starting with ffx0 not jpeg format". I think this is because the string variable in python writes the data in the file as a hex string.
The client code is as follows :-

```
Bitmap memoryImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgb, previewSize.width,previewSize.height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
if(memoryImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,100, baos)){
    try {
        if(count==0){
            byte [] Finalbaos = baos.toByteArray();
            int tempLen = Finalbaos.length;
            Log.v("Client","ImageBytes :"+ tempLen);
            String dataMeta = Integer.toString(tempLen);
            Log.v("Client","Integer Size :"+ dataMeta.length());
            PrintWriter tempOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            if(tempOut!=null){
                tempOut.write(dataMeta);
                Log.v("Client","data size sent");
                tempOut.flush();
            }

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            if(in!=null){
                Log.v("Client","read buffer created");
                String xyz = in.readLine();
                String temp = "recvd";
                Log.v("Client",xyz);
                if(xyz.equals(temp)){
                    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                    out.write(Finalbaos,0,tempLen);
                    out.flush();
                    Log.d("Client", "Client sent message");
                }
            }
```

server code:

```
import socket,thread
import string
import array
host=""
port=54321
s=socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
conn,address=s.accept()
data=""
mylen=0
dataRecv=0
file1 = open("myfile.jpg","w")
totalLength=""
length=conn.recv(1024)
conn.send("recvd")
mylen=int(length)

while dataRecv<mylen:
    newData=""
    newData=conn.recv(1)
    if not newData:
        break
    data+=newData
    dataRecv+=len(newData)

result= array.array('B',data.decode("hex"))
file1.write(result)
file1.close()
print len(data)
conn.close()
s.close()
```

can anyone let me know how to reconstruct the frame on server either in python or C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `mylen=len(length)` doesn't give you the length you're trying to send. it gives you how many bytes were read in the previsous `recv`. So you get the wrong lenght there.
- on your client side, you use `String xyz = in.readLine();` which will block until a newline character is encountered. but you never send a `'\n'` on the server side, instead you go waiting for a response from the client. so you have a deadlock there.
- you use `data.decode("hex")` on your recieved data. unless you do the equivalend of `data.encode("hex")` in java on the other side, that won't work. it should give you an error if the string is not a valid hex-representation of a binary string.
- `result` is an `array.array`, which you write to file. `file1.write` expects a string as argument, it gives you an error if you pass your `result` object.

so i can't even see why your code works at all, and why there's anything at all in your file.

Comment: mylen=len(length) was a silly mistake on my part. I have edited it and it should be int(length). Before sending the data of the frame, I am sending the size of the frame the server should receive.

Comment: Thankyou mata for pointing out the error in readline(). I was expecting that it automatically detects end of line/string.
Plus i was also mistaken on considering that python strings wrote data as "hex" encoded.
- I removed the encode() function and added '\n' to 'recvd' string send by the server and i was able to get the frame on my server :) Thanks a lot ! 
anyone who would like to know the code, just let me know.

Comment: @geekoraul do you still have the code?